# How do I use a custom react component as a geocoder input box?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am creating a simple mapbox-gl and react app. I have a `<App/>` component that contains two components `<Map/>` and `<Input/>`. I currently define my map and geocoder within the `<Map/>` component. Inside the `<Input/>` component, I have a contentEditable div that I would like to leverage as my geocoder input box.

I have a function inside `<App/>` that I pass down to `<Input/>` that gets me the current value in the contentEditable div. I am confused about how to 'apply' this query and get results.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome! You'll get much more useful responses if you include a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

There is already a [Geocoder React Component](https://github.com/mapbox/react-geocoder) for Mapbox that you could use.

Otherwise, there is this [Javascript client for Mapbox services](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-sdk-js).
Finally, if you want total control you could call the [Geocoding API](https://www.mapbox.com/api-documentation/?language=JavaScript#geocoding) directly.

For more information: https://www.mapbox.com/help/how-geocoding-works/

Comment: Thank you. I went with the total control option. The documentation is a little rough for a newb like me, but with a friend's help I was able to make good progress.

Comment: That's good to know! You should take a look at the JS client, it may save you a lot of time.
Finding the LatLng from a place's name is as simple as doing
 `client.geocodeForward('Eiffel tower') .then(res => console.log(res.entity.features[0].center))`